# Last word not showing when separating String into lines

Tags: php

When using var_dump on $arrTemp it is missing the last word
http://phptester.net

I can't see whats is wrong, i'm a newbie

This code is to separate a string into lines, if it reaches 20 chars

```
$arrMessage = str_split(stripcslashes("test asdasd"));
$arrTemp = array();
$line = 0;
$word = array();
$arrTemp[$line] = array();

foreach($arrMessage as $char) {

    if($char == " ") {
        //calculate numbers of chars currently on line + number of chars in word
        $numTotalChars = count($word) + (int) count($arrTemp[$line]);
        //if total > 20 chars on a line, create new line
        if($numTotalChars > 20) {
            $line++;
            $arrTemp[$line] = array();
        }
        $word[] = $char;
        //push word-array onto line + empty word array
        $arrTemp[$line] = array_merge($arrTemp[$line], $word);
        $word = array();
    } else {
        //if word is too long for a line, split it
        if( count($word) > 20) {
            $numTotalChars = (int) count($word) + (int) count($arrTemp[$line]);

            if($numTotalChars > 20) {
                $line++;
                $arrTemp[$line] = array();
            }

            $arrTemp[$line] = array_merge($arrTemp[$line], $word);
            $word = array();
        }
        $word[] = $char;
    }
}
```

Comment: PLEASE IGNORE THIS COMMENT: str_split(stripcslashes("adriano asdasd"));. You have a typo here it must be str_split(stripslashes("adriano asdasd"));. You have a debugger for those kind of errors.

Comment: @Barmar Wow!!  I don't use this function has a long time. I don't rely on those functions anymore. Anyway thanks to point me to tha?

Comment: Just delete your comment instead of adding "IGNORE THIS"

Comment: You don't need `(int)` before `count()`, it always returns an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you only add a word to `$arrTemp` when you get to a space, but there's no space at the end of the input string.

```
<?php
$arrMessage = str_split(stripcslashes("adriano asdasd"));
$arrTemp = array();
$line = 0;
$word = array();
$arrTemp[$line] = array();

foreach($arrMessage as $char) {

    if($char == " ") {
        //calculate numbers of chars currently on line + number of chars in word
        $numTotalChars = count($word) + count($arrTemp[$line]);
        //if total > 20 chars on a line, create new line
        if($numTotalChars > 20) {
            $line++;
            $arrTemp[$line] = array();
        }
        $word[] = $char;
        //push word-array onto line + empty word array
        $arrTemp[$line] = array_merge($arrTemp[$line], $word);
        $word = array();
    } else {
        //if word is too long for a line, split it
        if( count($word) > 20) {
            $numTotalChars = count($word) + count($arrTemp[$line]);

            if($numTotalChars > 20) {
                $line++;
                $arrTemp[$line] = array();
            }

            $arrTemp[$line] = array_merge($arrTemp[$line], $word);
            $word = array();
        }
        $word[] = $char;
    }
}
// Add last word if there's something left over
if (count($word)) {
    $numTotalChars = count($word) + count($arrTemp[$line]);
    if ($numTotalChars > 20) {
        $line++;
        $arrTemp[$line] = array();
    }
    //push word-array onto line + empty word array
    $arrTemp[$line] = array_merge($arrTemp[$line], $word);
}
var_dump($arrTemp);
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/Zncf4l)

Comment: Now the last char is duplicated